# C# VS2015 just randomly stops project when debugging http async response

Tags: c#, async-await

now I know I am probably doing something wrong as I am very new to async/await,.. but I am having a random issue I cant get past.

I am calling the Google Places API (successfully) and getting results.

```
 Response results = await Api.SearchPlaces(lat, lon, "");
```

results is populated with a response of 20 places which is great.
I am then trying to loop through them and add them to a list of places.

```
var places = new List<Place>();

  foreach (var place in results.Places)
  {
       places.Add(place);
  }
```

and in the debugger, as I hit the results.Places - visual studio just stops debugging.  No errors, it just stops.

if I debug over the results and in to the foreach loop fast, I maybe get 2-3 iterations through adding the place to my places list, then it stops, if I wait say 10 seconds, it stops the second I hit the first foreach iteration.

the point that VS just stops seems to be about the time that the Google lookup finishes.. but I just don't get why I cant just add the results to a list and why VS stops with no reason.

the entire method I am using to call the API is async and returning a task

```
public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task CreateAccountsFromGPSPositions()
{

}
```

I know this is probably a simple async/await thing but I just don't get why VS just stops when there is still code to run through..

am I not dealing with the results correctly?  can I not just foreach through and do stuff like I normally would with a result..

the method that is called to search is this:

```
async public static Task<Response> SearchPlaces(double latitude, double longitude, string query)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage resp;
            resp = await Client.GetAsync(String.Format("nearbysearch/json?key={0}&location={1},{2}&sensor=true&rankby=distance&keyword={3}", AppSecret, latitude, longitude, query));

            if (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(), typeof(Response)) as Response;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are going to want to read this article:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx.  It will change your life with async programming and error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Steve,
I spoke to a friend of mine who put me right on this.  Evidently the async/await in a Console app behaves differently than a Windows forms app or web app. I was getting a deadlock situation.. would be handy if VS told you that instead of just stopping with no error...

solution was to wrap my await call in a Task.Run and call .Wait() as well.

Completed code:

```
var task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(async () => await Api.SearchPlaces(lat, lon, ""));
task.Wait();
```

then

```
foreach (var place in task.Result.Places)
{
    places.Add(place);
}
```

Comment: In Windows Forms there is a different SynchronizationContext. You may find this article helpful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396